# Repeat one row in SQL Server n times - according on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data in one of my tables:

```
YEAR    MONTH     Cost
-------------------------
2018      1       25000
2018      2       32000
2018      3        9865
```

I would like to repeat rows for example if Month=1 then I would like to have 31 times this row, if Month=2 then 28 times for this row (actually according to number of days of each month)

How can I do that?

Thank you so much

Comment: create a calendar table with all days of the year and then simply join with that table

Comment: I can not have an extra table

Comment: why cant you have another table

Comment: You don't really have a choice.  SQL isn't very good at generating new data, it's good at extracting data which is already there.  A calendar table is an OK approach to use.

Comment: If you are _really_ not allowed to create a calendar table, then use a temporary table or a table variable. The number of records is relatively small (unless you are registering Bowerick Wowbagger's diary), so it's not that expensive having to regenerate it for every query.

Comment: @RuudHelderman, in this case it is even simpler with a cte creating 31 numbers via `VALUES`. This costs (almost) nothing. I placed an answer with this approach.

Comment: @Kaja Please can you confirm whether there is a constraint to only have one cost allowed per month and year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a calendar table, it will solve this and many future dates problems for you.

This solution generates one with a recursive CTE.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2020-01-01'

;WITH GeneratedCalendar AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = @StartDate,
        Month = MONTH(@StartDate),
        Year = YEAR(@StartDate)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.GeneratedDate),
        Month = MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.GeneratedDate)),
        Year = YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1, G.GeneratedDate))
    FROM
        GeneratedCalendar AS G
    WHERE
        G.GeneratedDate < @EndDate
)
SELECT
    T.YEAR,
    T.MONTH,
    T.Cost,
    G.GeneratedDate
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN GeneratedCalendar AS G ON
        T.YEAR = G.Year AND
        T.MONTH = G.Month
ORDER BY
    T.YEAR,
    T.MONTH
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select year, month, datefromparts(year, month, 1) as dte, cost
      from t
      union all
      select year, month, dateadd(day, 1, dte), cost
      from t
      where day(dateadd(day, 1, dte)) <> 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

This includes the date for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a calendar table to which you can LEFT JOIN your table or you can build one using numbers table/tally table.

Here's **[an excellent article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)** to read about this concept.

One way to do this demonstrated below-

```
select year, month,date=t.d cost from 
your table cross apply(
select
d=dateadd(d,r ,cast(cast(month as varchar(2))+ '-01-'+cast(year as varchar(4)) as date))
from
(
select top 31
r=row_number() over( order by (select null))-1
from
sys.objects s1 cross join sys.objects s2)t
where month(dateadd(d,r ,cast(cast(month as varchar(2))+ '-01-'+cast(year as varchar(4)) as date)))=month
)t
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses an inline table valued function with CROSS APPLY:

```
create function YearsMonths(@year int, @month int)
returns table
as
return
    Select @year [Year], @month [Month]
    from    master.dbo.spt_values t2 
    where t2.type = 'P' AND t2.number < CASE WHEN @month IN (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) THEN 31
                WHEN @month IN (4, 6, 9, 11) THEN 30
                ELSE CASE WHEN (YEAR(@year) % 4    = 0 AND
                                YEAR(@year) % 100 != 0) OR
                               (YEAR(@year) % 400  = 0)
                          THEN 29
                          ELSE 28
                     END
           END
GO
create table yearmonthcost ([Year] int, [Month] int, [Cost] int)
insert into yearmonthcost values
  (2018, 1, 25000)
, (2018, 2, 32000)
, (2018, 3, 9865)

select * 
from yearmonthcost ymc
cross apply dbo.YearsMonths(ymc.[Year], ymc.[Month])
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive CTE is you friend here
assuming that your table name is **T2**

```
with A as (
    select T.[year], T.[month], datefromparts(T.[year], T.[month], 1) AS D, T.[cost]
    from T2 T
    union all
    select T.[year], T.[month], dateadd(day, 1, A.D) AS D, T.[cost]
    from T2 T INNER JOIN A ON T.[year]=A.[year] AND T.[month]=A.[month] AND T.[cost]=A.[cost]
    where MONTH(dateadd(day, 1, A.D)) = MONTH(A.D)
)
SELECT * FROM A
ORDER BY A.[year], A.[month], A.D
```

Comment: This times out if you have two costs for the same year/month http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88935b/1

Comment: This was not in description and in sample data. But change is so simple as another AND. Changed to follow this comment

Comment: Thanks. I think it is important to establish if this is gathering monthly totals or monthly costs as they come in, so have asked Kaja the question directly. The change you made will not work if the costs are the same but this is a moot point if OP confirms that it is monthly totals.

Answer (score 0):

And yet one more:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(y INT, m INT, Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (2018,1,25000)
,(2018,2,32000)
,(2018,3,9865);
```

--the tally-CTE will generate 31 running numbers in just no time
--this CTE is used with `TOP` with a calculated count to retrieve the fitting count of numbers

```
WITH Tally AS(SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                                  ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                                  ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31)) t(nr))
SELECT *
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(t.y,REPLACE(STR(t.m,2),' ','0'),'01'),126)) D(FirstOfMonth)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1,D.FirstOfMonth)-1)) nr FROM Tally ORDER BY nr) AS multiplier;
```

the first cross apply will compute the first of your month ("20180101"), while the computation in `TOP` will add one month and go one day back. This is the last day of the month.

You did not specify your SQL-Serer version. This will be [much easier with `EOMONTH` (v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`DATEFROMPARTS` (v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

### UPDATE with SQL-Server 2012

try this with v2012+

```
WITH Tally AS(SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
                                  ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                                  ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31)) t(nr))
SELECT *
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP (DAY(EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(t.y,t.m,1)))) nr FROM Tally ORDER BY nr) AS multiplier
```